# aggregate dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss by minutes for groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mydata<-structure(list(lead_create = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("10.11.2017 4:47:26", 
                                                                                                                "10.11.2017 4:48:26", "10.11.2017 4:49:26"), class = "factor"), 
                      lead_id = c(24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 
                                  24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 24799522L, 
                                  24799522L, 24799523L, 24799523L, 24799524L, 24799524L, 24799524L, 
                                  24799524L), webmaster_identifier = c(430L, 430L, 430L, 430L, 
                                                                       430L, 431L, 431L, 431L, 431L, 431L, 431L, 431L, 430L, 430L, 
                                                                       430L, 430L, 430L, 430L), product = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
                                                                       ), .Label = c("gel", "Intoxic"), class = "factor"), lead_country = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                      1L, 1L), .Label = "Indonesia", class = "factor")), .Names = c("lead_create", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "lead_id", "webmaster_identifier", "product", "lead_country"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -18L))
```

I don't know  why, but in this example lead_create is factor! It is Date variable.

i need for group variables  webmaster_identifier,product,lead_country calculate count of unique lead_id by minutes.
Date format of lead_create is dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
i need that data was in such dataframe

```
      lead_create lead_id webmaster_identifier product lead_country
1 10.11.2017 4:47       1                  430 Intoxic    Indonesia
2 10.11.2017 4:47       1                  431 Intoxic    Indonesia
3 10.11.2017 4:48       1                  430     gel    Indonesia
4 10.11.2017 4:49       1                  430     gel    Indonesia
```

for time period from 10.11.2017 4:47:00-10.11.2017 4:47:59 for `webmaster=430` and `product =intoxic` and `lead_country=Indonesia` was only one unique lead_id.

for time period from 10.11.2017 4:47:00-10.11.2017 4:47:59 for `webmaster=431` and `product =intoxic` and `lead_country=Indonesia` was also only one unique lead_id.

for time period from 10.11.2017 4:48:00-10.11.2017 4:48:59 for `webmaster=430` and `product =gel` and `lead_country=Indonesia` was only one unique lead_id.

for time period from 10.11.2017 4:49:00-10.11.2017 4:49:59 for `webmaster=430` and `product =gel` and `lead_country=Indonesia` was only one unique lead_id.

How create such data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we need to  remove the suffix  string in the 'lead_create' and then get the  `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mydata %>%  
   mutate(lead_create = str_remove(lead_create, ":\\d+$")) %>% 
   distinct  %>%
   mutate(lead_id = group_indices(., lead_country))
#     lead_create lead_id webmaster_identifier product lead_country
#1 10.11.2017 4:47       1                  430 Intoxic    Indonesia
#2 10.11.2017 4:47       1                  431 Intoxic    Indonesia
#3 10.11.2017 4:48       1                  430     gel    Indonesia
#4 10.11.2017 4:49       1                  430     gel    Indonesia
```